# Cannot change text spacing and float to change text position

Tags: html, css

So, here is my problem. I am trying to create an email signature creator and I was writing my code but it is acting strange and putting in a strange spacing that I don't understand. I tried changing the float and the display but I can't because it all has to display inline and if it isn't floating right, then it doesn't position correctly. Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<div id = "allBody">
  <div id = "image">
    <img src = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id = "image">
  </div>
  <div id = "fullName">Billy Staples</div>
  <div id = "job"><i>Programmer</i></div>
  <div id = "line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#allBody {
  display: inline-block;
}
#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline;
}
#line {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
  margin-right: 25px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
#fullName {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: orange;
  }
#job {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

Basically, what I am trying to get is so that the name (Billy Staples) to be next to the job (Programmer) so that it doesn't look like there isn't that embarrassing tab-looking-thing before the name text.

A working version of this code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CyanCoding/he84kv8n/3/).

I believe this may be possible if I was to used a table but I have not completely understood table positioning and I am not very good at them. If you do believe this code would be improved by using a table, it would be appreciated if you could add an example I could follow until I got the hang of it.

Comment: Your padding top on your programmer div is what is causing the spacing. http://i.imgur.com/qBZbEol.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest approach I can think of would be a 1 line css negative margin (if this is not what you want, please clarify since I'm not 100% sure of your desired output):

```css
#allBody {
  display: inline-block;
}

#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline;
}

#line {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
  margin-right: 25px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

#fullName {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: orange;
  /* new (tweak value to your benefit) */
  margin-left: -86px;
}

#job {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="allBody">
  <div id="image">
    <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id="image">
  </div>
  <div id="fullName">Billy Staples</div>
  <div id="job"><i>Programmer</i></div>
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```

Or all inline:

```css
#allBody {
    display: inline-block;
}

#image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline;
}

#line {
    height: 200px;
    width: 7.5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: cornflowerBlue;
    margin-right: 25px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

#fullName {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: orange;
}

#job {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    /*padding-top: 40px;*/
    line-height: 2.2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="allBody">
    <div id="image">
        <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id="image">
    </div>
    <div id="fullName">Billy Staples</div>
    <div id="job"><i>Programmer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i> </div>
    <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```